# Checkerboard pattern in black and white plus red circle

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I am new here and beginner for matlab. I have this question that I have to solve. I have looked internet and this website to find the solution. But I couldn't get the exact solution. Here is the question.

> **Plotting in Matlab**
>
> "Create an image of a checkerboard pattern in black and white and mark the centers of all black squares with red circles in your image."

I am not allowed to use checkerboard command or other tool box commands. I have spent a lot of time and still cannot solve it.

One thing I can think of is creating a matrix composed of 0 and 1. Something like

```
m=zeros(10);
m(1:2:end,1:2:end) = 1; 
m(2:2:end,2:2:end) = 1;
```

Comment: You almost have it. See [`imagesc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html)

Answer (score 4):

You've created the checkerboard pattern correctly.  Now you just need to visualize it.  You can use [`image`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) or [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html):

```
imagesc(m); 
%// or
%//image(m);
```

The purpose of both commands is to display an image from a matrix.  This image follows a **colour map**.  The smallest value is visualized to be the lower end of the colour map while the largest scale is visualized to be the higher end of the colour map.

However `imagesc` additionally **scales** the output so that the smallest value and largest values encountered in the matrix go to the lower and higher end of the colour map respectively.

There are many colour maps you can choose from.  For the purposes of your checkerboard, use the `gray` colour map:

```
imagesc(m); colormap gray;
%// or
%//image(m); colormap gray;
```

For completeness, a list of all colour maps (excluding the new parula colour map introduced as of R2014b) can be found here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [izmiran.ru](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.gif))</sub>

---

Now the last thing you need to do is plot red circles where each black square is.  That can be done by finding all of the coordinates in your checkerboard that contain the value 0, then plotting these points in red:

```
%// Code from before... your code
m=zeros(10);
m(1:2:end,1:2:end) = 1; 
m(2:2:end,2:2:end) = 1; 

%// New code
imagesc(m); colormap gray;
hold on;
[row,col] = find(m == 0);
plot(row, col, 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 14);
```

`hold on;` is to allow more updates to the window that contains your checkerboard pattern.  If you tried to update the figure to add more content on it, the figure would **overwrite** with the new content and not keep the old content.  So it's important that you have `hold on;` there.

The [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) command used in this case finds all of the row and column locations in your checkerboard matrix `m` that have the value 0. After, we take these locations and [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) red circles.  These coordinates will serve as the centre of where the circles will be placed. I use `plot` to do this and ensure that we plot red circles (i.e. `r.`).  I also make the size of the marker large enough so you can see the red dots (i.e. `MarkerSize=14`) but not large enough to cover the black squares completely.

I finally get this image:

[image]

Comment: Great explanation as always!

Comment: @wonder you're welcome. Please consider accepting my answer if you no longer need help. That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my answer, to the left just below the up and down voting arrows. This tells the community you no longer need help. Good luck!